# Open file and scroll to bottom command line param?

Tags: command-line, scrolling

I'm new to vim.

I want to open vim from command line and have it scroll to the bottom of a file automatically.

The use case is opening logs.

Typically I open vim "vim log" and then scroll down using G. But I do this a lot. Does vim have a command line paramater to automatically scroll to the bottom like "vim -b log" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
vim log +$
```

The `+` bit tells vim to run a command after startup. The `$` command moves to the last line in the file. Depending on your shell, you might need `\` before the `$` was to tell the shell to not treat the `$` specially.

You can also put it before the file, which makes selecting from command history (e.g. up arrow in your shell) and modifying the filename easier, or making an alias:

```
vim +$ log
```

as an alias (using bash)

```
alias vimend="vim +$"
```

run like

```
prompt$ vimend /var/log/dmesg
```

Comment: The `$` character isn't required if you just want to go to the last line, simply putting `+` on the command line is sufficient.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang Agreed. In `vim --help`: `+   Start at end of file`